# Android flavor-specific entity reference

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In my strings.xml resource, I have defined an entity reference called product_name. I have done this because I use this product_name as part of other string resources.

For example, if I have this strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources [
    <!ENTITY product_name "Example App">
]>
<resources>
    <string name="welcome_message">Welcome to &product_name;</string>
</resources>
```

Is it possible to have a different entity based on which build flavor I'm running?